# Instantiating a .Net object by classname

Tags: .net

I have an abstract class Step, and many descendant Step classes that I would like to instantiate based on an XML document.

As such I would like to create an instance of a particular step class based on the type in the XML document

Step type="GenerateReport"
   ....
Step type="PrintReport"
   ....

How can I instantiate an object by specifying the classname (and ideally the parameters to be passed through to the constructor)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest option is the `Activator.CreateInstance` overload that accepts a `Type` and a `params object[]`. For the `Type`, you can *sometimes* use `Type.GetType(string)`, but this doesn't check all assemblies (just the current assembly and some system assemblies). If the name is assembly-qualified you'll probably be OK - but if it is just namespace-qualified (i.e. FullName) then you'll probably want to use `Assembly.GetType(string)` - i.e.

```
Type type = typeof(SomeKnownTypeInTheSameAssembly).GetType(fullName);
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type, args);
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you simply want to use the [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4.aspx) method:

```
var object = Activator.CreateInstance(null, "Classname");
```